# Terraform - cosmosdb cassandra schema block

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create cosmos db with cassandra api. And i want to pass the table - schema as a variable. can someone guide me how i can do that. I was using the following code

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_keyspace" "ks" {
  name                = "${var.key_space_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.resource_group_name}"
  account_name        = "${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.acc.name}"
  throughput          = 400
}

resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_table" "ct" {
  name                  = "${var.table_name}"
  cassandra_keyspace_id = "${azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_keyspace.ks.id}"
  schema  = "${var.table_schema}"
}
```

```
variable.tf file
variable "table_schema" {
  description  = "table schema"
}
```

```
abc.tfvars
table_schema = " column {\nname = 'test1'\ntype = 'ascii'\n}\ncolumn {\nname = 'test2'\ntype = 'int'\n}\npartition_key {\nname = 'test1'\n}\n}"
```

Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 68, in resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_table" "ct":
│   68:   schema  = "${var.table_schema}"
│
│ An argument named "schema" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "schema"?
╵

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ***not possible to pass the whole schema block as a variable*** because ***Terraform expects it to be a block while you are passing it as an argument*** .

[image]

If you want to pass it as a ***variable*** then you can ***use dynamic blocks*** like below :

**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_table" "ct" {
  name                  = "tableans"
  cassandra_keyspace_id = azurerm_cosmosdb_cassandra_keyspace.ks.id
  schema  {
      dynamic "column"{
          for_each = var.table_schema.columns
          content{
              name = column.value.name
              type = column.value.type
          }
      }
      dynamic "partition_key"{
          for_each = var.table_schema.partition_keys
          content{
              name = partition_key.value.name
          }
      }
      dynamic "cluster_key"{
          for_each = var.table_schema.cluster_keys
          content{
              name = cluster_key.value.name
              order_by = cluster_key.value.order_by
          }
      }
  }
}
```

***No changes in variable.tf***

**abc.tfvars**

```
table_schema = {
columns = [{
    name = "test1"
    type = "ascii"},
    {
    name = "test2"
    type = "int"}]
partition_keys = [{
    name = "test1"
    }]
cluster_keys = [
]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note :** ***Cluster Keys*** I have kept empty in the `tfvars` file thats why the ***dynamic block*** for `cluster_key` ***doesn't execute*** . If you want to include cluster keys as well then the below will be your `abc.tfvars` file :

```
table_schema = {
columns = [{
    name = "test1"
    type = "ascii"},
    {
    name = "test2"
    type = "int"}]
partition_keys = [{
    name = "test1"
    }]
cluster_keys = [{
    name = "test2"
    order_by = "Asc"
    }
]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]